# JQuery - How to get specified row containg unique element by javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablerow

HTML structure is mentioned below.
I want a JScript or JQuery that extract entire row if we pass "230" (unique identifier  in row) to function.

It should search in HTML tags with unique id - 230 and consider that row and click on "Dark Red"

```
<tbody id="avlForm:tnbts:tb" class="rf-dt-b">
  <tr id="avlForm:tnbts:3" class="rf-dt-r">
    <td id="avlForm:tnbts:3:j_idt152" class="rf-dt-c">230</td>
    <td id="avlForm:tnbts:3:j_idt156" class="rf-dt-c">Red</td>
    <td id="avlForm:tnbts:3:j_idt202" class="rf-dt-c">
      <a onclick="alert('Light Red')">Light Red</a> 
      <a onclick="alert('Dark Red')">Dark Red</a> 
      <a onclick="alert('Reddish')">Reddish</a> 
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="avlForm:tnbts:8" class="rf-dt-r">
    <td id="avlForm:tnbts:8:j_idt152" class="rf-dt-c">150</td>
    <td id="avlForm:tnbts:8:j_idt156" class="rf-dt-c">BLUE</td>
    <td id="avlForm:tnbts:8:j_idt202" class="rf-dt-c">
      <a onclick="alert('Night BLUE')">Night BLUE</a> 
      <a onclick="alert('Dark BLUE')">Dark BLUE</a> 
      <a onclick="alert('Light BLUE')">Light BLUE</a>                 
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: You must have tried something, post that code

Comment: I don't see an id=230 but value of td element

Answer (score 0):

First, add id to links with alerts. Then loop all `td` in row and trigger click:

```
<a onclick="alert('Dark BLUE')" id="dark-blue">Dark BLUE</a>

$.each("#avlForm:tnbts:tb td", function(){
    if($(this).text() == "230"){
        $('#dark-blue').trigger('click');
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi, this would be a solution, unfortunately if there were many rows and columns as you could freeze the browser (too many iterations)

Comment: @KevinLucich combine loop with setTimout(/*fonction_to_loop*/, 0)

Comment: @KevinLucich Or since your text will be unique, you can make some custom attribute with that text and then search by this attribute without looping.

Answer (score 0):

if you have already an unique value you can set the id row to "row#" (where # is the unique number). After for select a row with id "row_230" you can use:

```
$("#row_230")  //  to select a row
$("#row_230").click()  //  to trigger the click event
```

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score -1):

Create a selector to look for your ending id, then test the html of it's a tags until you find yor desired text and trigger it's click.

```
var wantedID = 230,
    target = $('[id$="idt'+wantedID+'"]');

$('a', target).each(function () {
    var html = $(this).html();
    if (html == 'Dark Red') $(this).trigger('click');
})
```

Comment: Why -1? isn't my response good, i create a solution, without touching him elements, isn't that good?

Comment: Oh, i see, i wrong interpreted where on that code is the id, my apologies.